# Where to find fruits market in Negombo, Sri Lanka?

Tags: shopping, sri-lanka, negombo

Where to find a fruit market (or a place where I can buy fruit at wholesale prices) in/around downtown Negombo, Sri Lanka?

Comment: I've been in Negombo for about four weeks now and have not found that fruits market yet. But there are road side stalls selling fruit near the bus station and also close to the clock tower i.e.: Green Road - Rajapakse intersection. Will be leaving Negombo soon, so this is it unless someone else finds it out and shares with the community.

Comment: Wholesale markets are not travel-relevant in my point of view. Voted to close.

Comment: You spent four weeks there and asked the internet rather than the people around you?